# subsets of consenters for each channel - seperate orderers of an organization per channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have to find a way to define subsets of consenters for each channel.

The main purpose is to seperate orderers of an organization per channel.

For example:

```
* I have Org1 and Org2:
        ** Org1 has orderes: orderer11, orderer 12
        ** Org2 has orderer: 21, orderer 22
* I want to create system channel which contains EtcdRaft consenter with all 4 orderers.
* I want to create 2 application channels, each one of them will contain EtcdRaft with 1 orderer from each org in the following way:
        ** channel1 with orderer11 and orderer 21
        ** channel2 with orderer12 and orderer 22
```

I tried to configure the desirable configuration on configtx.yaml file, but all my experiments failed.

Example of expected configuration:

```
Profiles:
/** System Channel **/
    mychannel
        Organization: OrdererOrg
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
                    OrdererType: etcdraft
                    EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                    - Host: orderer11.example.com
                    - Host: orderer12.example.com
                    - Host: orderer21.example.com
                    - Host: orderer22.example.com
        Consortiums:
            Organizations:
                - *org1
                - *org2
/** Application Channels **/
    channel1
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
                    OrdererType: etcdraft
                    EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                    - Host: orderer11.example.com
                    - Host: orderer21.example.com
        Consortiums:
            Organizations:
                - *org1
                - *org2
    channel2
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
                    OrdererType: etcdraft
                    EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                    - Host: orderer12.example.com
                    - Host: orderer22.example.com
        Consortiums:
            Organizations:
                - *org1
                - *org2
```

How can I apply the expected configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system channel is used by the ordering service as a template to create application channels. The **nodes of the ordering service that are defined in the system channel become the default consenter set of new channels**, while the administrators of the ordering service become the orderer administrators of the channel.

so you define `Orderer` at Profile application channel section is useless

but the ordering nodes can be added or removed from the channel by updating the application channel configuration

so if you want to use seperate orderers per channel,after create application channel ,remove the consenter set of your application channel config you can reference https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/config_update.html

https://kctheservant.medium.com/add-an-orderer-to-a-running-raft-based-orderer-cluster-b6a432da138c

I have use seperate orderers per channel successful at version 1.4.2,I think it is easier for version 2.3.x. because you can setup your fabric network without system channel.